# new product display content type not showing in products view

Tags: views, commerce

I've just started playing with drupal commerce which seems pretty good.
I'm using Kickstart v2-rc1. I created a new product display type (content type with a product reference field). Everything seems to work, I can create a new node of this type and create/add variation. I can see my product under the correct category.
However, when I use the product view (all product), my product doesn't appear in this list. What am I missing ? Is it an permission problem or the products view which is filtering my product ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the problem. The answer is probably obvious for a drupal expert but not for someone who just use drupal commerce out of the box.

Right, so the search facility (search box and 'all product' link ) use the search API which needs to be re-indexed when something changed.

For some reasons it wasn't. I'm expecting that adding a new product/entiry will triggered a reindexation but it doesn't. It seems also it could be done via the cron (but I haven't set any cron either, nobody told me to so). And, anyway, it seems the indexation was 'broken' (I changed one of the category name) so I add to recreate the indexes form scratch.

So the answer is , my searches need reindexation.

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the default backoffice view that is provided by Drupal Commerce. You can edit that view by going to http://yoururl.com/admin/structure/views/view/commerce_backoffice_products/edit

You can set the field filters in the view.

Comment: I found the problem is products view not the backoffice one. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to set the limit (Options list limit) to 10000 in the product reference field (/admin/structure/types/manage/product/fields/field_product).

As the default (no limit) not seems to take affect. I only saw the first 10 products available.